# Can I margin a synchronous Buck regulator to output all the way from 0V to VIN?

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, output, synchronous

When using a synchronous buck regulator ***without*** bootstrap supply for its top MOSFET, it should be possible to margin the output voltage all the way from 0V to VIN by feeding an additional CTRL voltage into the Feedback pin. The below graphic shows the output voltage as a function of the CTRL voltage:

[image]

However, when reading datasheets of such regulators, [e.g. this one](https://www.torexsemi.com/file/xc9263/XC9263-XC9264.pdf), they usually contain a minimum set voltage and do not spec the maximum voltage all the way to VIN. For example, in the linked datasheet, the minimum output voltage is given as about 12 % of VIN and the maximum is given as 15 V while the maximum input is 18 V. This is despite mentioning a duty cycle of 0-100 %.

So can they or can they not output from 0V to VIN (potentially with increased ripple) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximum output voltage depends on maximum duty cycle ; if you want to go all the way to Vin then the top FET has to be able to be on continuously, which usually means a PMOS. To use a better NMOS, some chips have a a charge pump driver to generate the required voltage above Vin. But even bootstrap chips can have high duty cycle: LTC3851 will go to 99% of Vin, so at that point, you got to wonder if the extra losses in a PMOS are worth the last 1%...

Besides, you won't get Vin at the output, there is still voltage drop across RdsON, inductor ESR, etc.

The last % before Vin (and the first % close to zero) will also depend on minimum off-time (and on-time), or how it can change frequency or skip cycles to keep the duty cycle high (or low) enough. Also if the top FET is fully on, you don't get any regulation.

Then you have the question of the current sense amp that monitors the FET or inductor current. Is it rail to rail? What is its common mode? Maybe it senses in a place where that doesn't matter, like Vin current, but maybe it senses in a place where output voltage matters, like inductor current. That will set some limits on Vout.

If you add an offset to the feedback node, the feedback error amp will always have its input at Vref, so it should not set any restrictions.

I think the XC9264 (the one with PFM) should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for raising awareness of the current sense circuitry. Just out of curiosity: why shouldn't an NMOS buck with charge pump *not* be able to achieve 100% duty cycle ? I thought the difference between PMOS or charge pumped NMOS is only price vs performance (with PMOS being cheaper but worse).

Comment: @tobalt. The charge pump is driven from the switch output. If the switch is fully on, then no charge pump action happens, the voltage drains from the boost cap and the mosfet slowly turns off.

Comment: @Kartman that's a bootstrap driver. I don't know if some buck chips have a real charge pump that can provide a constant gate drive no matter the duty cycle. Some FET drivers do, but adding a driver isn't reasonable in this case.

Comment: Some of the LTC chips I’ve come across use bootstrap drive for the high side.

Comment: @Kartman what you describe is a bootstrap supply, not a charge pump circuit as per switching regulator jargon. But upon searching I actually struggled to find any buck regulators with charge pump drivers. These seem to be more common for general purpose half-bridge or full-bridge ICs.

Comment: Yes if you use a H-bridge you want your motor to be able to run at full duty cycle so it needs a charge pump for the boosted supply.